# iphone dev - could clone ABRecord?

Tags: iphone, copy, clone, abrecord

I want to delete one ABPerson (say, person) in address book then add another one (say new), since some parts of attributes may be reused, I want to clone 'person' to 'new', here is my question, it seems there is NO function to do this clone, I found ABRecordCreateCopy but it seems to be MAC specified, Is there any api I could use to avoid copy each properties one by one ?
Thanks in advance!

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own version of `ABRecordCreateCopy` by generating a vCard representation and create an `ABRecord` from it. Following is the code snippet. Remember to release the returned instance once it's not used anymore.

```
ABRecordRef ABRecordCreateCopy (ABRecordRef record)
{
    ABRecordRef people[1] = {record};
    CFArrayRef peopleArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, people, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    CFDataRef vCardData = ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(peopleArray);
    ABRecordRef source = ABPersonCopySource(record);
    ABRecordRef duplicatedPerson = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(source, vCardData);
    ABRecordRef returnedPerson = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(duplicatedPerson, 0);

    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(vCardData);
    CFRelease(duplicatedPerson);

    return CFRetain(returnedPerson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did some cross-reading and it seems, there is no such copy function.
But there are some points about that topic:
You don't have to copy the values one by one, al least with `ABRecordCopyCompositeName` you can copy Prefix, Suffix, Organization, First name, and Last name at a time.

However if you can only use some parts of the existing record, why not set the not needed values in the existing record to null or overwrite the ones needed to change with new values. As you can only use parts of the existing person  you will have to do this even if you could use the `ABRecordCreateCopy`. And since you delete the old person anyway i dont see why you want to delete and not just change it in the first place.
The point is, as far as i see it, the only change in doing so would be a different ID in the `ABPhoneBook`. I can't imagine a situation, where this would be a problem and all other values can be changed.